# Example of situation where ACL unaware tools would grant unintended permssions

Tags: permissions, filesystems, acl

[This document](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919060634/http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) about File ACLs makes mention that the masking mechanism was put in place to solve the problem of

> ... POSIX.1 applications that are unaware of ACLs will not suddenly and unexpectedly start to grant additional permissions once ACLs are supported.

What would be an example of such a situation?

If there was a file with extended ACLs setup according to these intentions by the system admin:

1. The file owner should have `rwx` permissons
2. The users in the file's group should have no access (`---`)
3. Others should have no access (`---`)
4. An exception to the above three is that the system group `audit` has `r--` permissions on files

I would imagine the corresponding extended ACL for a file would be:

```
# file: path/to/file
# owner: foo
# group: bar
user::rwx
group::---
group:audit:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

In this example, if the `mask` mechanism was not in place and a tool unaware of extended ACLs attempted to change the group permissions to `--x` (it is a strawman argument) the `group::` entry would end up having `group::--x`. Why would this "unexpectedly ... grant additional permissions"?

```
# file: path/to/file
# owner: foo
# group: bar
user::rwx
group::--x
group:audit:r--
other::---
```

Based on my understanding, users in the owning group but not in the `audit` would gain the ability to execute. Users in the `audit` group but not the owning group would not. Users in both groups would gain the ability to execute. I don't understand why the `mask` is needed.

If I am misunderstanding something, please explain. It's possible that my strawman does not describe the situation that the quote is talking about. If that is the case, please describe such a situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mask and its link to the `S_IRWXG` bits weren't the case, applications that did various standard things with `chmod()`, expecting it to work as `chmod()` has traditionally worked on old non-ACL Unixes, would either leave gaping security holes or see what they think to be gaping security holes:

- Traditional Unix applications expect to be able to deny all access to a file, named pipe, device, or directory with `chmod(…,000)`. In the presence of ACLs, this only turns off *all* user and group permissions if the old `S_IRWXG` maps to the mask. Without this, setting the old file permissions to `000` wouldn't affect any ACL entries for specific users/groups and other users/groups would, surprisingly, still have access to the object.

  Temporarily changing a file's permission bits to no access with `chmod 000` and then changing them back again was an old file locking mechanism, used before Unixes gained advisory locking mechanisms, that [— as you can see — people still use today](http://prabindatta-myownblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/lock-folderdirectory.html).
- Traditional Unix scripts expect to be able to run `chmod go-rwx` and end up with only the object's owner able to access the object.  Again [— as you can see — this is still the received wisdom](http://washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html) even now, decades after the invention of Unix ACLs.  And again, this doesn't work unless the old `S_IRWXG` maps to the mask, because otherwise that `chmod` command wouldn't turn off any ACL entries for specific users/groups, leading to users/groups other than the owner retaining access to something that *is expected* to be accessible *only* to the owner.
- A system where the permission bits were otherwise separate from and `and`ed with the ACLs would require file permission flags to be `rwxrwxrwx` in most cases, which would confuse the heck out of the many Unix applications that complain when they see what they think to be world-writable stuff.

  A system where the permission bits were otherwise separate from and  `or`ed with the ACLs would have the `chmod(…,000)` problem mentioned before.

## Further reading

- Craig Rubin (1989-08-18).  [*Rationale for Selecting Access Control List Features for the Unix System*](http://fas.org./irp/nsa/rainbow/tg020-a.htm).  NCSC-TG-020-A.  DIANE Publishing.  ISBN 9780788105548.
- Portable Applications Standards Committee of the IEEE Computer Society (October 1997). 
  [*Draft Standard for Information Technology—Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX)—Part 1: System Application Program Interface (API)— Amendment #: Protection, Audit and Control Interfaces [C Language]*](http://simson.net/ref/1997/posix_1003.1e-990310.pdf)  IEEE 1003.1e.  Draft 17.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406545/5132