# File attributes. Unable to remove using sudo rm -rf in osx

Tags: files, macos

Looked around for what the following means:

```
-rw-r--r--+ Filea.a
```

The above file in OSX can not be removed with sudo rm -rf.

```
Operation not permitted
```

What does the "+" signify?
How does one remove such a file?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/572542/edit) your post to include the error message you get when trying to remove the file? As for your second question, the `+` character indicates that an [access control list (ACL)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347836/view-extended-acl-for-a-file-with-in-ls-l-output) has been defined for the file.

Comment: ls -le Files.a
0: group:everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown

Answer (score -1):

The + indicates you have acl on the file. 
do this command

```
getfacl file.a
```

It should show why you cannot remove the file.

Comment: OSX does not have getfacl. See link in AdminBee comment

Comment: then use that method to remove the ACL. same issue just a different method of setting ACL's 
And mark it solved so people will stop looking at your post.