# chmod returns: invalid mode:

Tags: linux, chmod, acl

I am trying to run the following command from Oracle ZFS docs and it fails:

```
$ chmod A+user:myusr:add_subdirectory:fd:allow /tank
chmod: invalid mode: ‘A+user:myusr:add_subdirectory:fd:allow’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information
```

Version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Oracle Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gebxb/index.html

Am I missing something?

Comment: Even if Linux supports ZFS, it does not support modern ACLs.The man page is related to the modern ACLs and the modern `chmod` from Solaris and does not apply to Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You’re missing the title of the document you’re reading: *Oracle Solaris ZFS Administration Guide*. It applies to Solaris, which is another operating system; you should look for documentation relating to ZFS on Ubuntu (or more generally, Linux).

[As the *Guide* says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/gbacb.html), on Solaris (and other operating systems like MacOS) the tools for setting and viewing ACL entries are the ordinary `chmod` and `ls` commands, to which ACL capabilities have been added.
On Linux-based operating systems they would instead be the separate `setfacl`, `getfacl`, `setrichacl`, and `getrichacl` commands.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406545/5132 for more.

Comment: Thanks :) Giving too much credit to Google makes me a bit blind..

Comment: Linux still uses the long outdated commands from a standard proposal: `getfacl` and `setfacl` but the related proposal has been withdrawn in 1997. Support for modern ACLs is de-facto non-existent on Linux distros, while it has been introduced on Solaris, AIX, Macos,...15 years ago.

Comment: There is a standard for ACLs, it is part of the NFS standard and it is the modern ACL concept. AFAIK, Linux does not yet implement full NFSv4 compatibility.

Comment: Psst!  Check out the second set of tools.